# Azure cosmos DB allows max 5 joins only in a query

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Cosmos db allows max 5 joins in a query. What happens when there is a need of more than 5  joins in a very complex query ?
How does one tackle that scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement it in Cosmos DB Stored Procedure but it failed as same as Cosmos DB SDK.

[image]

According to this [official blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/documentdb-raises-sql-query-limits/) , the limit will not be increased for the time being.

I suggest you split the query sql or adjust the data structure. After all, too many join times could also reduce query efficiency.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Splitting the query would lead to multiple calls to cosmos db. That is pretty inefficient as well. Think about a loop of n iterations hitting cosmos db n times. Its basically a tug of war between calling cosmos db n times dealing with network latency n number of times vs having n joins in the cosmos query. I am not sure if there is a better way to tackle this situation rather than just splitting the query

Comment: @Hary I think he limit number of joins to 5 times because Azure Cosmos DB  must also consider the efficiency of a single query. In fact, you could use Azure Csomos DB stored procedure to complete the query. Stored procedures are JS script running on the azure side , more efficient than the local.

Comment: Thanks Jay. But stored procedure won't solve my purpose as that would also have have the same 5 max limit. Efficiency wise yes, I can split the query and convert it in to a stores procedure in cosmos